# Bootstrap Glyphicons not appearing on chrome or phone test (phonegap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, phonegap

Currently coding an application via PhoneGap, however, I am having an issue with my glyphicons not appearing. I keep getting this message:

```
GET file://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I don't know what to do to fix this message.

Can anyone help to fix this error message and to get my icons appearing?

Comment: Fixed formatting and made question more clear

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: Check here: [Bootstrap icons example](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_asterisk)